# IronPython with Linq throwing ArgumentTypeException

Tags: linq, nhibernate, ironpython

I'm trying to extend my webapp with IronPython, which is working wonderfully so far, but I can't seem to get it to play nicely with my NHibernateLinq setup.

I'm making an **IQueryable<Case>** available to the IronPython code, and then I'm using the Linq methods to filter it down, such as:

```
Enumerable.Where[object](data, Func[object, bool](func))
```

This works fine, but because I'm using **Enumerable** instead of **Queryable**, it's pulling back ALL the records from the database, before running the **Where** function on them, when I want the Where clause to be added to the SQL query generated by NHibernate.

So I tried:

```
Queryable.Where[object](data, Func[object, bool](func))
```

But that simply yields:

```
Microsoft.Scripting.ArgumentTypeException: expected IQueryable[object], got Query[Case]
```

Am I missing something? Is this even possible?

Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic invariance is causing you problems, basically. A `Func<object, bool>` isn't convertible to a `Func<Case,bool>` - at least not until .NET 4.0

Note that `Queryable.Where` will require an expression tree, not a delegate. Does IronPython support expression trees?

If you can produce an expression tree in Python, can you make it `Expression<Func<Case,bool>>` instead of `Expression<Func<Object,bool>>`? If you can, that should make it work.

Comment: I did kinda wonder about that.  Can't find any evidence of IronPython supporting expression trees, so I've switched to using HQL instead of Linq. Cheers.